# How to remove Schlage lever mechanism?

Tags: doors, lock, doorknob

[image]

I'm trying to remove a schlage lever on an interior door (there is no lock, only a latch). I've removed

- the levers
- the latch
- the finish covers
- two screws that connect the two halves of the lever mechanism

Now I'm left with what's left in the picture above. There doesn't seem to be any more accessible screws or release pins. There *is* a collar nut in the center. I don't seem to be able to turn it (perhaps it needs a special tool).

Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the retaining ring, by rotating it anticlockwise.

[image]

They make a specialized castle nut wrench for installing/removing them. You should be able to loosen it using a pair of pliers, or screw driver. Though it looks like there might be some damage to the threads, so it might take a bit of effort.

Notice right near the arrow in the image above, that there's a flat spot with no threads.  Place a slotted screwdriver against the ridge of the castle nut, and gently tap the end of the screw driver. Hopefully that will loosen the nut just enough, that you'll be able to get it off by hand.

Comment: A screwdriver will work but be careful not to damage the threads.

Comment: Thanks -- ordered a castle nut wrench from ebay for a few bucks. Screwdriver or pliers are not working.